# Why doesn't OpenGL display the requested drawings correctly

Tags: c++, opengl, glut

Greetings I'm new to OpenGL and Glut. I made a function that displays the 4 dots that make the corners of a square without uniting the dots. The problem is when I run the project, the function doesn't display anything. 
I have a similar function that works with lines and displays some lines in the corners of the window which works perfectly. Please tell me what I'm doing wrong and how to fix it. Here are the two functions:

1. Using Lines. Works perfectly

   ```
   void Display2() {
       glColor3f(1,0.1,0.1); 
       glBegin(GL_LINES); 
           glVertex2f(1.0,1.0); 
           glVertex2f(0.9,0.9); 
           glVertex2f(0.8,0.8); 
           glVertex2f(0.7,0.7); 
           glVertex2f(0.6,0.6); 
           glVertex2f(0.5,0.5); 
           glVertex2f(-0.5,-0.5); 
           glVertex2f(-1.0,-1.0);
       glEnd();
   }
   ```
2. The one with dots. Does not display anything.

   ```
   void Display3() {
       glColor3f(1,0.1,0.1);
       glBegin(GL_POINTS);
           glVertex2f(100, 100);
           glVertex2f(200, 100);
           glVertex2f(100, 200);
           glVertex2f(200, 200);
       glEnd();
   }
   ```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default visible area in OpenGL ranges from -1 to 1 on each axis (the so-called normalized device coordinates).

In your line example, all the values are in this range and thus are visible. In the point example, the coordinates are simply outside of the screen. You can either change the coordinates to fit in the [-1,1] interval, or add a projection matrix that handles that for you.

Comment: Strange because I also have a predefined function for mouse clicks to specify the position clicked.. and when I click on one corner of the screen its either 1 1 or 1 300 or 300 300 or 300 1

Comment: This are then screen coordinates. You can, as mentioned, use a projection matrix if you want to specify the points in screen coordinates.

Comment: To elaborate further on what BDL meant: OpenGL does not deal with user input (mouse, keyboard, etc.) and there's no such thing as a "OpenGL coordinate system". OpenGL coordinate input can be transformed in whatever way desired. User input however happens in a very specific coordinate space, namely the space the mouse pointer does live in (and the OS usually does you the courtsey to translate it into window coordinate space). That is the space mouse events are reported in, and *you* are responsible to do the translation into whatever coordinate space you're doing your drawing.